# How to get FTP server's file list separated by new line

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to access a file list on a FTP server. My code is working fine but all results are showing on one line, I want links displayed as links, one per line.

This is what I tried:

```
$ftp_server = "abc"; 
 $ftp_user = "xyz";
 $ftp_password = "123";
 $path = "/";
if(ftp_login($conn,$ftp_user,$ftp_password))
{
 $contents= ftp_nlist($conn, $path); 
echo implode("\n",$contents)    ;

 }
?>
```

results are like:

```
file1 file2 file3
```

I want it to be like:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Windows you may actually need `\r\n` instead of just `\n` due to the way that Windows handles new lines.

PHP has a handy constant called `PHP_EOL` which will automatically use the correct one.

If you are outputting the text in `HTML` then rather than a new line, you actually need to separate each file with a line break. The `HTML` for a line break is `<br>`.

Try the following to see which one works for you.

```
echo implode(PHP_EOL, $contents); // New line
echo implode('<br>', $contents); // HTML line break
```